# Canvas isn't drawn in Tic-Tac-Toe Game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was programming a Tic-Tac-Toe game, but it says who goes first and enter the game loop without drawing the grid, even though it should draw the grid first. It should draw the grid first, but it doesn't do that.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
  <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
  //Setup
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  function getRandomFromInterval(interval) {
    return(Math.floor(Math.random() * interval));
  };
  function isNumberBetween(number, low, high) {
    return(number >= low && number <= high);
  };
  function circle (x, y, radius, color, filled) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    if (filled === true) {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fill()
    } else {
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.stroke();
    };
  };
  function Spot(x, y, cloneID, type) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.cloneID = cloneID,
    this.type = type
  };
  Spot.prototype.drawX = function () {
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x - 30, this.y - 30);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x + 30, this.y + 30);
    ctx.moveTo(this.x - 30, this.y + 30);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x + 30, this.y - 30);
    ctx.stroke();
  };
  Spot.prototype.drawCircle = function () {
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    circle(this.x, this.y, 30, "Black", false);
  };
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 100);
  ctx.moveTo(0, 200);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 200);
  ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 300);
  ctx.moveTo(200, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 300);
  ctx.stroke();
  var spot1 = new Spot(50, 50, 1, "");
  var spot2 = new Spot(150, 50, 2, "");
  var spot3 = new Spot(250, 50, 3, "");
  var spot4 = new Spot(50, 150, 4, "");
  var spot5 = new Spot(150, 150, 5, "");
  var spot6 = new Spot(250, 150, 6, "");
  var spot7 = new Spot(50, 250, 7, "");
  var spot8 = new Spot(150, 250, 8, "");
  var spot9 = new Spot(250, 250, 9, "");
  var availableSpots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var currentTurn = "";
  var playerSymbol = "";
  var opponentSymbol = "";
  if (getRandomFromInterval(2) === 1) {
    currentTurn = "player";
    playerSymbol = "X";
    opponentSymbol = "O";
    alert("The player is going first!");
  } else {
    currentTurn = "opponent"
    playerSymbol = "O"
    opponentSymbol = "X"
    alert("The opponent is going first!");
  };
  //Game
  while (!(spot1.type === "X" && spot2.type === "X" && spot3.type === "X") && !(spot1.type === "O" && spot2.type === "O" && spot3.type === "O")
  && !(spot4.type === "X" && spot5.type === "X" && spot6.type === "X") && !(spot4.type === "O" && spot5.type === "O" && spot6.type === "O")
  && !(spot7.type === "X" && spot8.type === "X" && spot9.type === "X") && !(spot7.type === "O" && spot8.type === "O" && spot9.type === "O")
  && !(spot1.type === "X" && spot4.type === "X" && spot7.type === "X") && !(spot1.type === "O" && spot4.type === "O" && spot7.type === "O")
  && !(spot2.type === "X" && spot5.type === "X" && spot8.type === "X") && !(spot2.type === "O" && spot5.type === "O" && spot8.type === "O")
  && !(spot3.type === "X" && spot6.type === "X" && spot9.type === "X") && !(spot3.type === "O" && spot6.type === "O" && spot9.type === "O")
  && !(spot1.type === "X" && spot5.type === "X" && spot9.type === "X") && !(spot1.type === "O" && spot5.type === "O" && spot9.type === "O")
  && !(spot3.type === "X" && spot5.type === "X" && spot7.type === "X") && !(spot3.type === "O" && spot5.type === "O" && spot7.type === "O") && availableSpots.length != 0) {
    if (currentTurn === "player") {
      $("canvas").click(function (event) {
        if (isNumberBetween(event.pageX, 0, 100) && isNumberBetween(event.pageY, 0, 100) && spot1.type === "") {
          availableSpots.pop(1);
          spot1.type = playerSymbol;
          if (playerSymbol === "X") {
            spot1.drawX();
          } else {
            spot1.drawCircle();
          };
          currentTurn = "opponent";
        } else if (isNumberBetween(event.pageX, 100, 200) && isNumberBetween(event.pageY, 0, 100) && spot2.type === "") {
          availableSpots.pop(2);
          spot2.type = playerSymbol;
          if (playerSymbol === "X") {
            spot2.drawX();
          } else {
            spot2.drawCircle();
          };
          currentTurn = "opponent";
        } else if (isNumberBetween(event.pageX, 200, 300) && isNumberBetween(event.pageY, 0, 100) && spot3.type === "") {
          availableSpots.pop(3);
          spot3.type = playerSymbol;
          if (playerSymbol === "X") {
            spot3.drawX();
          } else {
            spot3.drawCircle();
          };
          currentTurn = "opponent";
        } else if (isNumberBetween(event.pageX, 0, 100) && isNumberBetween(event.pageY, 100, 200) && spot4.type === "") {
          availableSpots.pop(4);
          spot4.type = playerSymbol;
          if (playerSymbol === "X") {
            spot4.drawX();
          } else {
            spot4.drawCircle();
          };
          currentTurn = "opponent";
        } else if (isNumberBetween(event.pageX, 100, 200) && isNumberBetween(event.pageY, 100, 200) && spot5.type === "") {
          availableSpots.pop(5);
          spot5.type = playerSymbol;
          if (playerSymbol === "X") {
            spot5.drawX();
          } else {
            spot5.drawCircle();
          };
          currentTurn = "opponent";
        } else if (isNumberBetween(event.pageX, 200, 300) && isNumberBetween(event.pageY, 100, 200) && spot6.type === "") {
          availableSpots.pop(6);
          spot6.type = playerSymbol;
          if (playerSymbol === "X") {
            spot6.drawX();
          } else {
            spot6.drawCircle();
          };
          currentTurn = "opponent";
        } else if (isNumberBetween(event.pageX, 0, 100) && isNumberBetween(event.pageY, 200, 300) && spot7.type === "") {
          availableSpots.pop(7);
          spot7.type = playerSymbol;
          if (playerSymbol === "X") {
            spot7.drawX();
          } else {
            spot7.drawCircle();
          };
          currentTurn = "opponent";
        } else if (isNumberBetween(event.pageX, 100, 200) && isNumberBetween(event.pageY, 200, 300) && spot8.type === "") {
          availableSpots.pop(8);
          spot8.type = playerSymbol;
          if (playerSymbol === "X") {
            spot8.drawX();
          } else {
            spot8.drawCircle();
          };
          currentTurn = "opponent";
        } else if (isNumberBetween(event.pageX, 200, 300) && isNumberBetween(event.pageY, 200, 300) && spot9.type === "") {
          availableSpots.pop(9);
          spot9.type = playerSymbol;
          if (playerSymbol === "X") {
            spot9.drawX();
          } else {
            spot9.drawCircle();
          };
          currentTurn = "opponent";
        }
      });
    };
  };
  </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop. The player never has a chance to make a move because your `while` loop never completes. Organize your game around events, not a `while` loop.

Comment: I tried disabling the loop for a test, but it still tells who goes first before drawing the canvas.

Comment: [I literally copied your code](https://jsfiddle.net/wjrsj4y2/) and removed the loop at the end. Nothing more. The grid is getting drawn as expected.

Comment: I used a click event and some functions and it works now :)